# How do I count the number of rows in an array?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

My task is to grab a 2-dimensional table from cells on a worksheet into a 2-dimensional array, delete some or all of the rows (right terminology?) from testing, and then paste what's left into a worksheet.

To determine the range for pasting I need to know the length of the edited array. This is where I'm challenged.

```
// This gets the array which is 3 columns wide and X rows (X will vary)
  var termEmp = spreadsheet.getRangeByName("roeList").getValues();  
// e.g. termEmp = [ ["Bob", 1, "day", "key"] ["Cindy", 2, "day", "it"] ["Laura", 1, "night", "we"] ]

// Then I find the number of rows that actually have data 
numRows = termEmp[0].length;             // result = 3

// A for loop with counter i tests if the second element equals 2 of each row and deletes each array row if it's there
// In this example I want to delete the row with Cindy because of the 2
// To do this is use the splice method to delete the second row thusly:
termEmp.splice(i,1);                    // i = 1 in the for loop

// After testing all elements, and deleting the rows I want, I then need to count the number of rows remaining (to create a range for pasting into the worksheet)
numRows = termEmp[0].length;            
// This is SUPPOSED to count the number of rows remaining (first element is ALWAYS non-blank)
```

Here's my problem. For this example the number of rows after the splice goes from 3 to 2. I looked at the array to confirm this.

But in my code termEmp[0].length STAYS at 3. I can't use it to define my range for pasting.

What's needed to get the count right?

Answer (score 2):

For number of rows, you can get the length of the full array.

```
 var numRows = termEmp.length
```

What you're getting with `termEmp[0].length` is the number of columns in first row.

**EDIT**
OP indicated the answer "doesn't work" (which is false) however, as a courtesy here's subsequent code that helps his followup question to identify members in an array contain another array (effectively 2-dimensional spreadsheet data). The below code will take all memembers from `termEmp` that are an array, and inserts them into `cleanedArray`.

```
var cleanedArray = [];
for(var i=0;i<termEmp.length;i++){
  var singleMember = termEmp[i];
  if(Array.isArray(singleMember)){
    //makes a clean array with only 2d values
    cleanedArray.push(singleMember);
  }
}
var numberOfMembers = cleanedArray.length;
Logger.log(numberOfMembers);
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried that and it doesn't work. It gives me a big number that I can't figure out where it came from. In my actual worksheet (I simplified things above) what's left in the array is three rows with 7 elements each. The result of termEmp.length is 88!! Huh? Wha?

Comment: But your comment above is a great one: How do I count the number of rows that have a first element?

Comment: I can assure you that  `var numRows = termEmp.length`  does work and it is the answer to the question you posted. I have no doubt that it's not returning the result you are expecting however, that is is because something else in your code is not behaving as you intend.  The fact that you have 88 instead of 7 or whatever means you're array is not being reduced as you expect it.

Comment: @Richard normally I don't answer followup questions, but your question was elementary enough that  I've updated my answer to include how to find rows that contain a first element (effectively finding arrays with array).  Kindly note that I did look at your profile and it appears you've asked several questions on StackOverFlow, yet never `accepted` a single answer. StackOverFlow operates on a reputation-based system which takes this heavily into account. Thus, I'd  be most grateful if you would please click `accept` to this answer. Thanks and good luck.

Comment: To pgSystemTester: Okay, sure. But how to I accept? I don't see any button on this page anywhere that says 'Accept answer' or anything like that. Where's this magic button?

Comment: @Richard I think it's green check mark to left of my answer.

Comment: Nothing like that on my screen. All there is is a flag that turns red when I hover over it.